# How to open a Flutter dialog no matter where the user is within the app

Tags: dart, dialog, flutter, flutter-navigation

I'm working on a Flutter project where I need the ability to show the user a dialog no matter where they happen to be within the app.  Currently I'm executing the showDialog() function in the root level widget that main() kicks off.
  That widget implements WidgetsBindingObserver so that I can listen for when the app moves from the background to the foreground via the didChangeAppLifecycleState() function. Anytime this happens I make a request to a service provider and depending on the results I need to show a dialog.
  The users will be navigated to some other route anytime this happens, and that's where I seem to be running into trouble. Below is the stripped down function that performs the API call and subsequent showDialog() attempt.  But nothing ever happens.  I tried wrapping it in a 2 second timer thinking maybe it was an issue of the app just coming back into the foreground, but that didn't make a difference.

```
void _fetchSuperAwesomeStuff() {
  final apiCaller = new SuperAwesomeStuffAPI();
  apiCaller.fetchSuperAwesomeStuff().then((List<SuperAwesomeStuff> superAwesomeStuffs) {
    if (superAwesomeStuffs != null && superAwesomeStuffs.length > 0) {
      SuperAwesomeStuff superAwesomeStuff = superAwesomeStuffs[0];

      // .... DOING STUFF WITH THIS SUPER AWESOME STUFF .... //

      // NEED TO SHOW A DIALOG.
      showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (_) => new AlertDialog(
          title: Text('Test Title'),
          actions: <Widget>[
            new FlatButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
              child: new Text('Close'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
    }
  });
}
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass a `BuildContext` for the `context` variable, and that context needs to be mounted (the corresponding element) in the tree when you make the call.

Alternatively, you could send a message/stream from your superawesome logic to any part of the app that has a context and listens to the stream. From here you could call the dialog.

Comment: I would rather stick with your first suggestion, so I don't have to worry about implementing the dialog in multiple different locations.  How would I go about getting the BuildContext that is mounted, or creating a BuildContext to mount?

Comment: I'm actually going to go with your message/stream suggestion instead.  It's probably better that I'm more deliberate where I allow this dialog to show because otherwise, I may show it when it's not a got UX for the user.  This way I can only listen for it in widgets where I know it's good to show.